# Translation Workbench don't reflect changes in Object screen

Tags: custom, workbench, translation

I'm using Translation Workbench to translate Custom field labels, but after adding a translated value to it some fields don't show the translated value in the object (Accounts and others) screen or take random time (from seconds to days) to show it.

Seems like a server cache issue as cleaning cache or even accessing by other machine makes no difference.

The issue affects two client sandboxes.
If I test it in a playground the labels are displayed correctly. Only a logoff/login is enough.

Any ideas?